# Overwrite executing bash script files

Tags: bash

What will happen if the executing bash script file is overwritten? Will it continue execute the old file or overwritten file ?

For example
/etc/test.sh has the following contents

cp /test.sh /etc/test.sh

Comment: Did you try it yourself? What happened?

Answer (score 22):

bash generally does *not* load the entire script in advance, so overwriting the script can have unpredictable consequences. For example, I just created a script containing this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo start old file
sleep 20
echo end old file
```

...and ran it. While it was sleeping, I overwrote it with this slightly different script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo started new file
sleep 20
echo end new file
```

Resulting in this output:

```
$ ./test.sh 
start old file
./test.sh: line 4: 0: command not found
end new file
```

What happened was that bash had read through the "sleep 20\n" line (including the line terminating newline) before sleeping. When it continued after that, it read the next command *from the next byte position in the file*, and since the second line had gotten two bytes longer ("start" -> "started"), it wound up reading the last two bytes of the new sleep line ("sleep 20\n" -> "0\n"), trying to execute "0" as a command, and getting an error. It then runs the final line of the new contents. Pretty messy, right?

Fortunately, there's a way to force bash to load the entire script into memory so it won't get confused if it gets changed while running:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
    echo start old file
    sleep 20
    echo end old file
    exit
}
```

The `{` forces the shell to read at least through the matching `}` in order to properly parse the command, and the `exit` then makes sure it'll never try to execute anything that gets added after that `}`.

BTW, I was testing this with bash version 3.2.48(1)-release (on OS X 10.8.5); other versions may behave differently...

UPDATE: Other versions do indeed behave differently. I tried the same test with version 4.3.0(1)-release (under NetBSD 6.1.4), and it continued to run the old code after the file's contents had been replaced. Apparently it now buffers the file in 8KB blocks (see [this unix.se answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121013/how-does-linux-deal-with-shell-scripts#121025)).

Comment: Under bash 5..0.3(1)-release on linux, it reads in 8KB blocks... but this doesn't prevent the error (in the version without the {}s), because, after the sleep is done, it seeks back to the position in the file just after the sleep!  Strange behavior.  {}s still protect it, good answer.

Comment: So on recent bash versions this trick no longer prevents runtime script modification? Do other shells still allow this trick or have they all switched to partial buffering? While script modification during runtime should not be done anyways it still feels like a regression to remove the ability to prevent runtime modification via this trick.

Comment: @user2280032 As far as I know the `{ ... exit; }` trick still works, but it really is a *trick*, not something the shell is required to allow. I'd consider modifying a script during execution to be a case of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), meaning that the shell can legitimately do *anything* and you're not really allowed to complain about it. Or, to put it another way, you can't expect the shell to react in a reasonable way when you do something unreasonable to it, and modifying a script during execution is unreasonable.

Answer (score -1):

The shell loads the script into memory and spawns a separate process, so the old script will continue to run *unmodified*.

Obviously, if you try to re-run it you'll get the new version.

If you're trying to introduce some new functionality during runtime, I would suggest writing to a temporary file and then executing that file using either the `$()` or `` (backtick) syntax to spawn a new process.

*Alternatively*, you can use `exec` to replace the currently running program completely.

Comment: Good advice in general, but it seems that there's no guarantee that bash will have read the *entire* original file up front; rather, it appears to read scripts in chunks of fixed size - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20722200/45375. Thus, overwritten content *could* get executed.

Comment: This answer starts with an incorrect statement and seems rather muddled.  "The shell loads the script into memory" - no, it effectively reads as it goes; run Gordon Davisson's example to demonstrate that.  "and spawns a separate process" - After it has started reading the script?  No, bash doesn't do that.

Answer (score -3):

Another mechanism, similar to what Donovan mentioned, is to just `cat` the file to stdout and pipe that into `bash`:

```
cat my_script.sh | bash
```

However, I don't know if there are any gotchas with pipe buffering on a given OS. (I'm on Ubuntu 18.04).

And of course, this only works for scripts that only depend on one source file that's being modified.

Comment: From here, it looks like at least GNU `cat` is unbuffered: https://superuser.com/a/896684/733549

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem in general (although it will probably work if the script is small enough, in which case the whole file will be read into cat's input buffer and/or the pipe's buffer all at once).  If the file is overwritten before cat is done reading it, then the problem happens.