# How to run shell script on specific git commit?

Tags: python, git, shell

I want to run `run.sh` to check the results of my codes, which takes about 30 hours.
But I can't wait to add other features to my codes.
However, I found there are some potential dangers:

- [Edit shell script while it's running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3398258/8380054)
- [Edit shell script and python script while it's running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61690477/8380054)

In my case, I want `run.sh` running with all files are fixed while I keep editing more features on python files, which may have bugs.

For example, here is my git log

```sh
* commit 6d1931c0f5f6f7030f1a93d4f7496527c3711c1f (HEAD -> master)
| Author: deeperlearner
| Date:   Fri Aug 13 10:37:21 2021 +0800
|
|     Version to be run by shell script
|
```

How can I force `run.sh` run on commit `6d1931` while I keep doing commits?

```sh
* commit 059706b752f4702bc5d0c830c87e812a7bbaae27 (HEAD -> master)
| Author: deeperlearner
| Date:   Fri Aug 13 10:38:21 2021 +0800
|
|     Buggy commit that may destroy `run.sh`
|
* commit 6d1931c0f5f6f7030f1a93d4f7496527c3711c1f
| Author: deeperlearner
| Date:   Fri Aug 13 10:37:21 2021 +0800
|
|     Version to be run by shell script
|
```

I currently have solutions: use `docker` or just copy the whole codes to other directory.

But I wonder if there is any method that can force shell script to execute on specific commit hash ID?

Comment: Use `git worktree` to create a safe space for the script to run.  Then continue hacking away in a different directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one use case for which `git worktree` is well suited.  You basically create a new branch at the desired commit and make a copy of the working directory at that branch.  For example, if you're at the top-level of your working tree and want to run the script on the current HEAD, just do:

```
$ git worktree add ../bar
Preparing worktree (new branch 'bar')
HEAD is now at b2ceba9 Add d
$ cd ../bar
$ # Run long running script here
$ cd ../foo
$ # Edit files, create new commits, profit
```

(In this example, `foo` is the name of the top level directory of the repo.)  There are options to worktree to work with a particular commit rather than HEAD.  Read the fine manual for details.