# Bash differences in changes to running scripts

Tags: bash

I'm scratching my head about two seemingly different behaviors of `bash` when editing a running script.

This is not a place to discuss WHY one would do this (you probably shouldn't). I would only like to try to understand what happens and why.

### Example A:

```bash
$ echo "echo 'echo hi' >> script.sh" > script.sh
$ cat script.sh
echo 'echo hi' >> script.sh
$ chmod +x script.sh
$ ./script.sh
hi
$ cat script.sh
echo 'echo hi' >> script.sh
echo hi
```

The script edits itself, and the change (extra echo line) is directly executed. Multiple executions lead to more lines of "hi".

### Example B:

Create a script `infLoop.sh` and run it.

```bash
$ cat infLoop.sh
while true
do
    x=1
    echo $x
done
$ ./infLoop.sh
1
1
1
...
```

Now open a second shell and edit the file changing the value of `x`. E.g. like this:

```bash
$ sed --in-place 's/x=1/x=2/' infLoop.sh
$ cat infLoop.sh
while true
do
    x=2
    echo $x
done
```

However, we observe that the output in the first terminal is still `1`. Doing the same with only one terminal, interrupting `infLoop.sh` through `Ctrl+Z`, editing, and then continuing it via `fg` yields the same result.

### The Question

Why does the change in example A have an immediate effect but the change in example B not?

PS: I know there are questions out there showing similar examples but none of those I saw have answers explaining the difference between the scenarios.

Comment: Do not change a script, while it is running. Most shell implementations (and I think this includes the standard GNU bash) open the script and read from the script file piece by piece. If you modify the script file during this time, the behaviour is unpredictable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually two different reasons that example B is different, either one of which is enough to prevent the change from taking effect. They're due to some subtleties of how `sed` and `bash` interact with files (and how unix-like OSes treat files), and might well be different with slightly different programs, etc.

Overall, I'd say this is a good example of how hard it is to understand & predict what'll happen if you modify a file while also running it (or reading etc from it), and therefore why it's a bad idea to do things like this. Basically, it's the computer equivalent of [sawing off the branch you're standing on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tyvhq7uhTM).

**Reason 1**: Despite the option's name, `sed --in-place` does not actually modify the existing file in place. What it actually does is create a new file with a temporary name, then when it's finished that it deletes the original and renames the new file into its place. It has the same name, but it's not actually the same file. You can tell this by looking at the file's inode number with `ls -li`:

```
$ ls -li infLoop.sh 
88 -rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 39 Aug  4 22:04 infLoop.sh
$ sed --in-place 's/x=1/x=2/' infLoop.sh
$ ls -li infLoop.sh 
4073 -rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 39 Aug  4 22:05 infLoop.sh
```

But bash still has the old file open (strictly speaking, it has an open file handle pointing to the old file), so it's going to continue getting the old contents no matter what changed in the new file.

Note that this doesn't apply to all programs that edit files. `vim`, for example, will rewrite the contents of existing files (unless file permissions forbid it, in which case it switches to the delete&replace method). Appending with `>>` will *always* append to the existing file rather than creating a new one.

(BTW, if it seems weird that bash could have a file open after it's been "deleted", that's just part of how unix-like OSes treat their files. Files are not truly deleted until their last directory entry is removed **and** the last open file handle referring to them is closed. Some programs actually take advantage of this for security by opening(/creating) a file and then immediately "deleting" it, so that the open file handle is the only way to reach the file.)

**Reason 2**: Even if you used a tool that actually modified the existing file in place, bash still wouldn't see the change. The reason for this is that bash reads from the file (parsing as it goes) until it has something it can execute, runs that, then goes back and reads more until it has another executable chunk, etc. It does not go back and re-read the same chunk to see if it's changed, so it'll only ever notice changes in parts of the file it hasn't read yet.

In example B, it has to read and parse the entire `while true ... done` loop before it can start executing it. Therefore, changes in that part (or possibly before it) will not be noticed once the loop has been read & started executing. Changes in the file *after* the loop would be noticed after the loop exited (if it ever did).

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096478/overwrite-executing-bash-script-files) (and Don Hatch's comment on it) for more info about this.

Comment: "Changes in the file after the loop would be noticed after the loop exited (if it ever did)." Is it *would* or *might*? *Would* implies that bash interprets lines immediately as they're read, and that it has no input buffering. Is that the case?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The detail that it does not reload the code in loops is the crucial part as I see it. So reading this and your linked answer do I understand it correctly that bash loads at least the next code block into memory?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I haven't looked at the source (or done anything like a systrace), but according to Don Hatch's comment, at least under bash 5..0.3(1)-release on linux, it reads in 8KB blocks, but then apparently dumps the excess, seeks back to the end of the current chunk and re-reads from there. Which seems like a weird way to do it, but presumably there are reasons... Anyway, every version I've tested does pick up changes after the currently-executing parseable chunk.

Comment: @Seriously Again, I haven't looked at the relevant source code, but my understanding is that reads *and parses* executable chunks (my term), which means that it's not even re-reading from memory, it's reading and parsing it once and then re-re-re-executing it from the parsed form.