# Bash interpreter executes the commented commands after modifying the bash file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

For convenience, I sometimes keep all execution commands within a single bash file and run them according to my applications. Let's say I have a bash script `exec.sh` as shown below.

```
python a.py
#python b.py
```

I notice that sometimes when I run `exec.sh` to execute `python a.py` and modify the script before the previous execution finishes:

```
#python a.py
python b.py
```

the first execution will continue to run `python b.py`, even after finishing `python a.py`.

**My question is: why does it continue?**

I suppose the first execution only see this. It seems unreasonable to me that the program will runs a comment.

```
python a.py
#python b.py
```

My suspection is that the bash interpreter works line-by-line, so at the begining it only sees `python a.py`, but when it finishes, it will read again the file and see `python b.py` being available.

The operating system is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with a bash version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

I will appreciate any thoughts or any possible reasons that cause this situation.

thanks.

Comment: The short answer is that it isn't safe to modify a running script; it can cause even weirder problems than this. Exactly how bash handles the file seems to depend on the bash and/or OS version. See my answer to ["Overwrite executing bash script files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096478/overwrite-executing-bash-script-files).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks a lot! That exactly answeres my question and even provides a solution.

Comment: I suggest to close this question with Gordon's link as duplicate.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for the suggestion, but I think it not straight-forward to everyone, at least me, to ask the right question at the first place. I would prefer leaving this question here for someone who will have a similar thought/observation.

Comment: @hpwww Actually, that's why we mark questions as duplicates -- the idea is that it's better to have all the answers to essentially similar questions in just one place, and have the related questions all point readers/searchers to that collection. See ["Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).